# Why sorting table does not work in react with useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      rank: 1,
      name: "John",
      age: 29,
      job: "Web developer",
    },
    {
      rank: 2,
      name: "Michael",
      age: 35,
      job: "Businessman",
    },
    {
      rank: 3,
      name: "Karl",
      age: 43,
      job: "Fashion Designer",
    },
    {
      rank: 4,
      name: "Adolf",
      age: 53,
      job: "Fashism",
    },
    {
      rank: 5,
      name: "Armen",
      age: 11,
      job: "Fortnite player",
    },
    {
      rank: 6,
      name: "Artak",
      age: 19,
      job: "Front-end developer",
    },
    {
      rank: 7,
      name: "Elon",
      age: 52,
      job: "Businessman",
    },
    {
      rank: 8,
      name: "Alik",
      age: 20,
      job: "Waiter",
    },
    {
      rank: 9,
      name: "Erik",
      age: 18,
      job: "Manager",
    },
    {
      rank: 10,
      name: "Sako",
      age: 50,
      job: "Economist",
    },
  ]);
  return (
    <div>
      <table style={{ margin: "3rem auto" }}>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
              onClick={() => {
                console.log(data);
                return setData((prev) => {
                  return prev.sort((a, b) => {
                    const aRank = a.rank;
                    const bRank = b.rank;
                    return bRank - aRank;
                  });
                });
              }}
            >
              Rank
            </th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Job</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((item) => {
            return (
              <tr key={item.rank}>
                <td>{item.rank}</td>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td>{item.age}</td>
                <td>{item.job}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I have correctly formatted all of my code!
I was just mapping through data and whenever rank is clicked, it should sort text in a decreasing order and I am using useState, however the text in the table does not change, but **bold** data changes! **bold**. So I just dont understand the principle of working state, everything seems to be fine for me, if you help me I would be really grateful!

Comment: what is setData((prev)

Comment: @RahulMohanty: `setData` is the value setter function from `useState`.  You can learn about React and the `useState` hook [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Answer (score 2):

The `sort` function [sorts the array *in place*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and returns a reference to the same array.  So, as far as React is concerned, the state value is still pointing to the same array and hasn't changed.  So there's no reason for it to re-render.

You can spread the resulting array values into a new array reference to tell React that it's a new array:

```
setData((prev) => [...prev.sort((a, b) => b.rank - a.rank)]);
```

(Also, you don't need to `return` the result of `setData`.  Because it has no result, and a click handler doesn't do anything with a returned result.)

Answer (score 1):

data.sort((a, b) => a.rank - b.rank) is sorting the data array based on the rank property of each object in the array. The function (a, b) => a.rank - b.rank is a comparison function that sort() uses to determine the order of elements.

Here's how it works:

If (a.rank - b.rank) is less than 0, sort() will sort a to an index lower than b (i.e., a comes first).
If (a.rank - b.rank) returns 0, sort() leaves a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements.
If (a.rank - b.rank) is greater than 0, sort() will sort b to a lower index than a (i.e., b comes first).
So, in your case, the data array is being sorted in ascending order of rank.

```
setData([...data.sort((a, b) => a.rank - b.rank)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work by returning a copy of the sorted array, and thus a different array from prev.
Like so:

```
              onClick={() => {
                return setData((prev) => {
                  return [...prev.sort((a, b) => {
                    const aRank = a.rank;
                    const bRank = b.rank;
                    return bRank - aRank;
                  })];
                });
              }}
```

[Here an example](https://reactplayground.vercel.app/#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-qlaZAAGkxAR7PnVdGhQAWWNJlMmgBiYhQ8rAnhI1JgKDAcXaBGbQ0LkeLqqqfPLbcrAZNZBs9moM6jGpI8c73KG3ZrfYHYBzu7n4oXqrLQsTx5IVZjcLIBHSu6GrZFoufp5wj2Qj8DoJA4PYYhZE6bwum6d6esuQoAGxrtW77EGI-Lfmq+7CrqAFGr2dAuJYzhQFatr2o606wZGN7zAhPJISQADsaFviAKSeDhv7xpqXZETWGbju02a5kqdEFvBz4PiQAAcHEbo42FSS2+6agADIJqZwqa-g6LRboMZysksQRJYvuuNZJOsqlJr+wqKYRukgJsfLRkZcFFmZ3oitpz6viayxYXgvH7vGAWWYBXG+PQl6Imps4qnSJQouc8hEBEBBzLM4oADxQGA1q4s++WtIaqQkN4WSpMEwDqLmBBxJAJqxvIDBiBERBhSAUKGKVllDOV8riFAg2LgVawTZNU3ys+s01XVDUaNlKCECa+CQIZcL9Qtk2eAAwo4Ej8vV2J4u6s2zZl2VzFStKtPk+Q4PI1o4sE+JMdd96JHdJDEggQOvTaCDrcQz0UiQhofV9+0-UMRKkGIwjLrUYgIGW6UI9dSPQ6jAq1IamPLtjOOTbdOX42jlhqgT-Jk+T8yGCUdKM+TLPsz9hiGPD8wzTj9N88NLBEPKAvXSNuIAHIBvlovi8LJBS2QCTy2LEuzVLcqGuritDfM6sEJrhsK2NJvDUQho7FkFuMWSrQILmODPWAOhYLDV0I5TuVK5bQT8jAWT1W7aQkwKA1+4bRDjcAodYOH-KGOr41R5bsfxwgr7J6LqcG1rMe4nH7sINGOeF2nyuF8XYcpuXedM0bdvimlfMs7zBvq9bUC22VotiJVMAS-LRUlQcrcQIY6Wou0cB-KQsDUF19gYpQICGEAA)